# API Telegram Обработка getUpdates vs setWebhook

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота, на 70 процентов уже закончил, всё вроде бы работает классно, но вот только протестировать на тысячах и десятках тысяч пользователей возможности сейчас нету, так как бот рассчитан именно на такое достаточно объемное количество пользователей, бот связан с бизнесом, поэтому после прлдакшна нужно точно знать что бот потянет этот трафик и у заказчика всё будет классно.

На данный момент я использую явный `getUpdates` и бот стучит телеграмм серверу каждые n-сек для проверки, пришло ли новое сообщение, причем если я не ошибаюсь работать это должно в одном потоке, так как если я запущу несколько потоков для обработки сообщений `getUpdates` я потеряю целостность и приоритет сообщений, то есть какое за каким сообщением шло, разве что можно синхронизировать посредством счетчика или каналов. Хотя если запустить в пяти горутинах  к примеру и попытаться синхронизировать, может выйдет что-то классное?

Я подумал что как раз из-за вот таких "стучаний" `getUpdates` может теряться весомая часть времени, так как с вебхуками "стучать" не приходит, потому что теперь нам приходится только ловить уже полученные сообщения, мне многие говорили что лучше использовать вебхуки, но я ещё не разу с ними не работал, так как не было нужды. Я не думаю что всё только одними вебхуками ограничится, я надеюсь на максимальную производительность бота без ненужных движений.

У меня вообще бот разделен на несколько частей, причем всё это поделено на отдельные части, обработка сообщений в отдельном канале, работа с базой в отдельном потоке завязанном на канале, то есть не абы как на одном потоке, а всё как надо с тестированием и максимальной многопоточностью.

Это больше теоретический вопрос, если будут вопросы по серверу на котором будет стоять бот, то это выделенный сервер c хорошими характеристиками, может даже лучше будет:

- 8 GB RAM
- 4 CPU
- 100 GB SSD
- 100 Mbit port

Нужно точно значить как дальше действовать так как права на ошибку нету.
Пожалуйста подскажите, укажите все нюансы обработки сообщений вебхуками/getUpdates и будет ли работать корректно бот с таким объемом пользователей.